# upgrade from spring-security-saml2-core to Spring Security SAML2 service provider

Tags: spring, spring-security, okta, spring-security-saml2

We are using spring-security-saml2-core for SSO Okta Integration for the web application.

GitHub:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml

This project is in maintenance mode and will each End-of-Life on 6 October 2021. Please use Spring Security’s SAML support instead.

I need to upgrade SAML library to Spring Security SAML2 service provider
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login

There are a few questions:

what is the SAMLEntryPoint equivalent class or option in the New library (SAML2 service provider)?
What is the process to initiate the SSO Flow from SP?

Comment: I have same question, can you please give information if you have any conclusions ?

Comment: I implemented  by referring following example, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/saml2.html. if your application is very old then you need to add AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to init param.